# How to convert an array of bits to a single char in java?

Tags: java, char, byte

I am working with an array of 8 bits and I am trying to convert it to a single char in Java. I am trying to do something along the lines of

```
byte[] bytes2 = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        char c = (char) bytes2);
```

It is throwing a compilation error that I can not case a byte[] to a char. I have gotten it to compile, but not work correctly by assigning char c to just one of the elements of the array. I am just stuck on this part, and would appreciate a little bit of help. 
Thank you

Comment: First of all byte[] is an array of bytes, not of bits!

Comment: [Possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38678429/522444)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`byte[]` is array of bytes, and 1 byte is 8 bit, 1 char is also 8 bit.

You initiate `byte[]` with `{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}`; It means your store 8 * 8 = 64 bits in `bytes2` variable.

So you can't store 64 bits data into single char (8 bit).

But you can do this:

```
byte[] bytes2 = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
char c = (char) bytes2[0]; // store first element (8 bit) into single char (1 bit) and cast it.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert it to a one single `char`. Instead of that you can convert it to a single `String` and then convert that to a `char` array like below,

```
    byte[] bits2 = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    String value = new String(bits2);
    char[] chars = value.toCharArray();
```